# I changed my router, can I still access my server with a static ip?

Tags: ip, dhcp, windows-server

My last router used IP range 192.168.1.1-255 with subnet mask 255.255.255.0. I've got a new router, but this one used a IP range 192.168.10.1-255, with the same subnet.

I can't ping or access the server by its host name anymore. Its connected to my router, so maybe I can change my IP of my pc to 192.168.1.something, 123 for instance, and then login to change that IP?

Or do I need to pull it out of the closet and attach a screen, mouse and keyboard to it and do it manually?

Comment: a) If server's IP is static, configure your new router's LAN to 192.168.1.0/24, or, backward, your server to 192.168.10.0/24; b) *I can't ping or access the server by its host name anymore* - from Lan or from Internet? If last - configure prot mapping or ВЬЯю

Answer (score 1):

If the server has a statically assigned IP address (on the host, not in the router/switch config), then yes, you will need to do it manually. You cannot access a x.x.1.x address from a x.x.10.x network with your current setup.

You can likely change the subnet your new router uses from x.x.10.x to x.x.1.x if you're feeling up for it, and the firmware supports it.

Comment: No :(, my (sucky router) does not support changing subnet. And its statically defined on the server. Its like a maxi tower inside the closet... there goes the weekend :P  Meh :D

Answer (score 0):

What I did since the server had a static IP assigned in the properties for the connection (Windows server), I took my laptop and assigned a static on the same subnet. So if the server was assigned 192.168.1.55, with my new router dishing out ips on 192.168.10.100-255, I could manually set my laptop to 192.168.1.123, and BAM - contact! I was able to remote in, change the IP of the server to the new subnet and assing my laptop back to DHCP :D Problem solved.